# How do I make my bot send images and how do I create a command that shuts it down?

Tags: python

I tried to create a bot which replies to text with either a witty reply from one of our teachers or an image. However, when I write the word "chungus" the bot doesn't reply with anything. I tried to print something at that line and it doesn't work. Also, I wrote a command to try and shut the bot down and send a text whenever it closes, but that too doesn't work. I'm new to python if you haven't figured it out

EDIT: I tried to make a command for the image reply, so I edited the code as well

EDIT: The *new* error is this

```
Ignoring exception in command chungus:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Andrei\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:/Users/Andrei/cnvagalati/botdiscord.py", line 49, in chungus
    await ctx.channel.send(file=discord.File(paul9_path))
  File "C:\Users\Andrei\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\discord\file.py", line 73, in __init__
    self.fp = open(fp, 'rb')
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'c:/Users/Andrei/cnvagalati/botdiscord.py\\images\\paul9.jpg'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Andrei\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 903, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\Andrei\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 859, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Andrei\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'c:/Users/Andrei/cnvagalati/botdiscord.py\\images\\paul9.jpg'
```

EDIT: The file path:

```
C:\USERS\ANDREI\CNVAGALATI
├───.vscode
└───images
```

```
import discord 
import os 
import random 

from dotenv import load_dotenv
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
from PIL import Image

load_dotenv()
bot=Bot(command_prefix="!")
DISCORD_TOKEN = 'TOKEN'
project_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
images_dir = os.path.join(__file__, 'images')
paul9_path = os.path.join(images_dir, 'paul9.jpg')

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == bot.user or message.author.bot:
        return
    Profi_quotes=[
        'Ce pizdele ma sii faci bai cajbecule',
        'Gaura care iti mareste Laura',
        'Ce balarii vorbesti acolo ma',
        'Bre',
        'Ce pula mea faceti aicea',
        'Taci in pula mea',
        'Ma cac si ma pis pe materia ta',
        'E TAAAAAAAAAAAAAARFA',
        'Spleen'
    ]
    if message.content == "cnva":
        response = random.choice(Profi_quotes)
        await message.channel.send(response)
    if "pula" in message.content:
        mention = message.author.mention
        response = f"stai ma pe cur {mention}"
        await message.channel.send(response)
    if 'minza' in message.content:
        await message.channel.send("My God, copilu...")
    if 'moisa' in message.content:
        await message.channel.send("Pizdele mortilor ma-sii cajbecule")
    if message.content == "stop":
        await bot.logout()
    
    await bot.process_commands(message) 

@bot.command()
async def chungus(ctx):
    await ctx.channel.send(file=discord.File(paul9_path))

@bot.command()
async def Domni(ctx):
    await ctx.channel.send("nananananana")

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    await bot.change_presence(activity = discord.Game('Tema la engleza') )
bot.run(DISCORD_TOKEN)
```

Comment: the error means `paul9.jpg` does not exist in the current directory. We cannot help you unless you tell us the full directory structure

Comment: @Chase my directory structure is C:/Users/Andrei/cnvagalati/botdiscord.py/paul.jpg

Comment: please post the file path accurately. That is very important. You've posted a path to a file that is not even named `paul9.jpg`, not even that - your path indicates the `paul.jpg` file is inside a folder named `botdiscord.py`, a folder cannot have that name. Please see [how to write file structure](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147467/is-there-a-good-way-to-represent-file-structure-in-a-question-answer)

Comment: my bad
this is the path:
```
Folder PATH listing for volume OS
Volume serial number is E235-1A8C
C:.
└───.vscode
```

Comment: please paste the **full structure** in your post. not comment. There's an `edit` button right under the post

Comment: right i did that

Comment: is the python file in `CNVAGALATI`, and the picture you're looking for in `images`?

Comment: yeah you're right @Chase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error indicates there isn't any file named `paul9.jpg` in the current directory. Which is true, since your file is inside `images/`.

You need to give the correct path relative to the current directory.

```py
if message.content == "chungus":
    await message.channel.send(file=discord.File('images/paul9.png'))
    print("huehuehuehue")
```

However, this is a relative path and is not very robust if you don't run the script from the same directory as the script itself. Instead, you should use [`os.path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html) functions

If your directory structure looks like-

```
C:\USERS\ANDREI\CNVAGALATI
├───.vscode
├───images
├   └───paul9.jpg
└───botdiscord.py
```

then you can get the path to `CNVAGALATI` like so

```py
import os

project_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
```

Now, you need to get the path to `images`

```py
images_dir = os.path.join(project_dir, 'images')
```

Now whenever you need a path to any file inside the images directory. You can just `os.path.join(images_dir, name_of_file)`

So for the file `paul9.jpg`

```py
paul9_path = os.path.join(images_dir, 'paul9.jpg')
```

You can now use pass this to `discord.File`

Comment: yeah you're right, but i still have a question
how do i call on the cnvagalati folder? like i write like a string or just ```project_dir = os.path.dirname(cnvagalati)``` ?

Comment: please note that `__file__` is a builtin variable that refers to the current file. so if you do `os.path.dirname(__file__)` - it literally gives you the path to your `CNVAGALATI` folder. You do not have to do anything else. `project_dir` is the path to that folder

Comment: oh right, I was actually asking how to write that line
i thought i had to replace ```__file__``` with cnvagalati

Comment: i tried it and i'm still getting the same error .
maybe i should just give up

Comment: @andrei4563 please post the error message, what path did it look in?

Comment: i'm posting it in the original post, one moment @chase

Comment: @andrei4563 `images_dir = os.path.join(__file__, 'images')`, are you sure this is what the line is supposed to be? why are you joining the `'images'` directory with `__file__`? you should be joining it with `project_dir`, `os.path.join(project_dir, 'images')`.

Comment: yep you're right that was my mistake 
it works now!!!!! thanks a lot for being patient with me!!!!!!! :DDDDDD